# Iterate over two dict, match on key values and return concatenated values

Tags: python, parsing

I am iterating over two dictionaries and when I find a match on keys I concatenate values from both dictionaries and create a url and store the results in a new list.

`database_dict` is static and will never change. However the second dictionary `cross_ref_dict` is based on values from a file that I am parsing.
So in a nutshell the `database_dict` will always have more values then the `cross_ref_dict`.

Below you will find my current solution, which works fine when the amount of elements in both dictionaries is the same. But when they are different I receive an empty list. How do I handle this situation and return concatenated values only for those that are found in `database_dict`?
I would only like to concatenate the values if the keys match, if there is no match or no value is found I would like that nothing is returned.

```
database_dict = { 'CLO' : 'https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ols/ontologies/clo/terms?iri=http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/',
             'EFO' : ' https://www.ebi.ac.uk/efo/',
             'ArrayExpress' : 'https://www.ebi.ac.uk/arrayexpress/experiments/',
             'ATCC' : 'https://www.atcc.org/Products/All/', # + .aspx
             'BioSample' : 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/biosample/?term=',
             'CCLE' : 'https://portals.broadinstitute.org/ccle/page?cell_line=',
             'Cell_Model_Passport' : 'https://cellmodelpassports.sanger.ac.uk/passports/',
             'ChEMBL-Cells' : 'https://www.ebi.ac.uk/chembldb/cell/inspect/',
             'ChEMBL-Targets' : 'https://www.ebi.ac.uk/chembldb/target/inspect/',
             'Cosmic' : 'https://cancer.sanger.ac.uk/cosmic/sample/overview?id=',
             'Cosmic-CLP' : 'https://cancer.sanger.ac.uk/cell_lines/sample/overview?id=',
             'DepMap' : 'https://depmap.org/portal/cell_line/ACH-000830',
             'GDSC' : 'https://www.cancerrxgene.org/translation/CellLine/',
             'GEO' : 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=',
             'IARC_TP53' : 'https://p53.iarc.fr/CellLines.aspx',
             'IGRhCellID' : 'http://igrcid.ibms.sinica.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cell_line_view.cgi?cl_name=',
             'KCLB' : 'https://cellbank.snu.ac.kr/english/sub/catalog.php?page=detail&CatNo=59&strQ=', # + &submit1=Find+it
             'LiGeA' : 'http://hpc-bioinformatics.cineca.it/fusion/cell_line/',
             'LINCS_LDP' : 'http://lincsportal.ccs.miami.edu/cells/#/view/',
             'PharmacoDB' : 'https://pharmacodb.ca/cell_lines/',
             'PRIDE' : 'https://www.ebi.ac.uk/pride/archive/projects/',
             'Wikidata' : 'https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/',
             'test' : 'test',
             'test2' : 'test2'
             }

cross_ref_dict = {'CLO': 'CLO_0007996', 'EFO': 'EFO_0002253', 'ArrayExpress': 'E-MTAB-3610', 'ATCC': 'CRL-5871', 'BioSample': 'SAMN10988000', 'CCLE': 'NCIH1436_LUNG', 'Cell_Model_Passport': 'SIDM00697', 'ChEMBL-Cells': 'CHEMBL3308893', 'ChEMBL-Targets': 'CHEMBL2366205', 'Cosmic': '2125229', 'Cosmic-CLP': '908469', 'DepMap': 'ACH-000830', 'GDSC': '908469', 'GEO': 'GSM1682805', 'IARC_TP53': '21539', 'IGRhCellID': 'NCIH1436', 'KCLB': '91436', 'LiGeA': 'CCLE_790', 'LINCS_LDP': 'LCL-1838', 'PharmacoDB': 'NCIH1436_1017_2019', 'PRIDE': 'PXD011896', 'Wikidata': 'Q54907807'}

# if the keys in dicts match, concatenate the base link from `database_dict` with the appropriate 
  value from `cross_ref_dict`
key_values['Cross-ref'] = [(str(database_dict.get(k, 0))+str(cross_ref_dict.get(k, 0))) for k 
                          in set(database_dict.keys()) | set(cross_ref_dict.keys()) if 
                          database_dict.keys() == cross_ref_dict.keys()]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the intersection of the `keys`, and then simply iterate over it.

something like:

```
set(cross_ref_dict.keys()).intersection(set(database_dict.keys()))
```

This will keep only the keys that are mutual to both dictionaries, regardless of the size of each one of them. Then you can simply iterate on the intersected keys with no worries.

So using your logic:

```
[database_dict.get(k) + cross_ref_dict.get(k) for k in set(cross_ref_dict.keys()).intersection(set(database_dict.keys()))]



# ['https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/biosample/?term=SAMN10988000', 'https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ols/ontologies/clo/terms?iri=http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/CLO_0007996', 'https://www.ebi.ac.uk/chembldb/target/inspect/CHEMBL2366205', 'https://cancer.sanger.ac.uk/cell_lines/sample/overview?id=908469', 'https://www.ebi.ac.uk/pride/archive/projects/PXD011896', 'https://www.ebi.ac.uk/arrayexpress/experiments/E-MTAB-3610', 'https://cancer.sanger.ac.uk/cosmic/sample/overview?id=2125229', 'http://lincsportal.ccs.miami.edu/cells/#/view/LCL-1838', 'https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q54907807', 'https://depmap.org/portal/cell_line/ACH-000830ACH-000830', 'https://www.atcc.org/Products/All/CRL-5871', 'http://hpc-bioinformatics.cineca.it/fusion/cell_line/CCLE_790', 'https://p53.iarc.fr/CellLines.aspx21539', 'http://igrcid.ibms.sinica.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cell_line_view.cgi?cl_name=NCIH1436', 'https://cellmodelpassports.sanger.ac.uk/passports/SIDM00697', 'https://www.cancerrxgene.org/translation/CellLine/908469', 'https://cellbank.snu.ac.kr/english/sub/catalog.php?page=detail&CatNo=59&strQ=91436', 'https://portals.broadinstitute.org/ccle/page?cell_line=NCIH1436_LUNG', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSM1682805', 'https://www.ebi.ac.uk/chembldb/cell/inspect/CHEMBL3308893', 'https://pharmacodb.ca/cell_lines/NCIH1436_1017_2019', ' https://www.ebi.ac.uk/efo/EFO_0002253']
```

Answer (score 1):

use a dictionary comprehension

```
results={key:data for (key,data) in database_dict.items() if key in cross_ref_dict.keys()}
print(results)
```